# Covariant Expression<Func<TBase, bool>>

Tags: c#, covariance

We have some common code. We'd like to have a method that accepts an `Expression` like below

```cs
public interface ISmallInterface
{
    // ...
}

public interface IExample<TBase>
{
    IQueryable<TBase> Where(Expression<Func<TBase, bool>> predicate);
}

public class SmallClass : ISmallInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

And from this we have some basic implementations

```
public abstract class AlphaBase<TBase> : IExample<TBase>
{
    public IQueryable<TBase> Where(Expression<Func<TBase, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In our core logic we use this to build components. And then over here in this `Gamma` example, we'd like a method or property exposing an `IExample<ISmallInterface>`.

```
public class Beta : AlphaBase<SmallClass>
{
    // ...
}

public class Gamma
{
    public IExample<ISmallInterface> GetThing()
    {
        var b = new Beta();
        return b;
    }
}
```

However, this gives a compiler error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Beta' to 'IExample<ISmallInterface>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Changing `IExample` to use a covariant type parameter fixes this conversion issue, but breaks the `Where` method.

```
public interface IExample<out TBase>
{
    IQueryable<TBase> Where(Expression<Func<TBase, bool>> predicate);
}
```

Gives compiler error

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TBase' must be invariantly valid on 'IExample<TBase>.Where(Expression<Func<TBase, bool>>)'. 'TBase' is covariant.

In our case, we were able to work with just `Func` parameters.

```
public interface IExample<out TBase>
{
    IQueryable<TBase> Where(Func<TBase, bool> predicate);
}

public abstract class AlphaBase<TBase> : IExample<TBase>
{
    public IQueryable<TBase> Where(Func<TBase, bool> predicate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs. However, it would be convenient to work with `Expression<Func<TBase, bool>>`.

Is there some kind of work around to use `Expression<Func<TBase, bool>>` with a covariant type?

(dotnet core 2.2, if that matters, and I think C#7.3)

Comment: Variance is about the same level as type inference. ("var"). It must by known and 100% sure, what type it is in reality at compile time. With Variance you allow the compiler to add the necessary casts automaticly. All these inferred automatism do not exist in expression trees That has to be done manually. The compiler resolves Generics of Expressions to concrete types, but in case of covariance, it cannot say 'it's this type' or 'its that type'. There is an implicit cast done somewhere. This has to be done explicit in the Expression. It's not an answer, maybe a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple enough, and seems to follow "the Linq way."

Just make an extension method with the correct signature and implement it there. There's no `Where` method in the interface now. Following the example above, code looks something like

```cs
public interface IExample<out TBase>
{
    // no Where, Count, or FirstOrDefault methods that accept Expression defined here

    // This is a lazy loading method and doesn't execute the query
    IQueryable<TBase> GetAll(ApplicationUser user);
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<TBase> Where<TBase>(
        this IExample<TBase> repository,
        ApplicationUser user,
        Expression<Func<TBase, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return repository.GetAll(user).Where(predicate);
    }

    public static int Count<TBase>(
        this IExample<TBase> repository,
        ApplicationUser user,
        Expression<Func<TBase, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return repository.GetAll(user).Count(predicate);
    }

    public static TBase FirstOrDefault<TBase>(
        this IExample<TBase> repository,
        ApplicationUser user,
        Expression<Func<TBase, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return repository.GetAll(user).FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```